# jStorage limit in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, jstorage

I'm setting a jStorage key using `$.jStorage.set("blah", largeDataString);`. The large datastring in question is 3mb. It works fine in all browsers except Chrome. Why is this?

http://www.jstorage.info/

Comment: chrome only gives you 2.5 million chars, which is fewer bytes than 3 million unicode chars uses.

Comment: @dandavis but this comment says 2.5million chars is 5mb. My file size is only 3? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values#comment8787385_3260214

Comment: @rickyduck you can store 5 million actual bytes, 5MB, but when you store a javascript string each char uses two bytes, so you can effectively store only half that amount. Firefox gives you a full 5 million js string chars, so it can store twice as much un-encoded text as chrome. IE is in-between Chrome and firefox, some weird amount that's not a factor of 2.5m or 5m... JSZip is a good way to effectively double-quadruple the available space.

Comment: @dandavis - cheers, I will check jszip. Weirdly though I tried on chrome this morning with no issues.